# load .swf file quickly at client side !

Tags: php, codeigniter, flash

Any tips or methods(encryption, plugins etc) to load flash files (i.e. swf) as quickly as possible at the client side ???

consider files size is between 5MB - 10MB....

Answer (score 3):

make sure gzip/deflate and http caching are active during transport

Comment: can you provide me some link or example of what you have mentioned ...

sorry i am a beginner in the field of web. :(

Comment: First google result: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html Dunno if its any good - you will have to do your own research.

Answer (score 0):

If you can break up your files, you have the option to load a small file first and then bring in additional files as needed or at least once the initial interface is up.  I no longer activly develop for flash, so this might be a bit outdated, but I always had the best results when I structured my desktop applications with the ultimate goal of easy portability to the web...

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought I read desktop in your question, until I read @stillstanding's reply. This answer may still apply though...

Answer (score 0):

You mean, load them more quickly than a standard `<embed>`? Hardly, seeing as the file is so and so large, and that number of bytes needs to be transferred to the client in any case.

Make sure compression is enabled as stillstanding says. There's probably not much more you can do except work on the Flash files themselves, reducing the quality of embedded images, splitting it into several files, reducing embedded fonts, etc..